# "Polyakov trick" for general relativity

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, string-theory, variational-principle, action

In introductory String Theory textbooks, one typically starts with the Nambu-Goto action
\begin{equation}
S_{NG} \sim \int d^2 \sigma \sqrt{\dot{X}^2 - X'^2}
\end{equation}
and then arrive later at the Polyakov action
\begin{equation}
S_{P} \sim \int d^2 \sigma \sqrt{-g} g^{\alpha\beta} \partial_{\alpha} X_\mu \partial_\beta X^\mu
\end{equation}
with $g$ a redundant worldsheet metric field that gets gauged away. This action agrees with the NG action on-shell, but has better mathematical properties due to the lack of square root over the *physical fields*, i.e. the $X_\mu$, which makes it more amenable to quantization.

The Einstein-Hilbert action has a similar square root:
\begin{equation}
S_{EH} \sim \int d^4x \sqrt{-g}R
\end{equation}
Is there a similar "Polyakov trick" for the EH action that moves the square root off of a physical field (i.e. the metric) by introducing extra redundant fields?

Comment: For what it's worth, one can reformulate the metric in terms of a  [vielbein](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/vielbein).

Comment: @Qmechanic interesting. Is there a concomitant action in this formalism? The linked resource doesn't seem to mention one.

Comment: Search for the "Palatini action in tetrad formalism".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For what it's worth, one can reformulate general relativity in terms of a [vielbein](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/vielbein) and a [spin connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_connection), cf. e.g. Ref. 1.

References:

1. D.Z. Freedman & A. Van Proeyen, *SUGRA,* 2012; sections 8.3 + 8.4.